# Using C# code pivot result using Automapper Nuget

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, automapper

I want to convert source data to destination using auto mapper.

Review below image.[image]

Source has 3 columns ID, Name, Status

Using C# code, I want to PIVOT result into destination using AutoMapper.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Source
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
    public string Name3 { get; set; }
}

Mapper.CreateMap<Source[], Destination>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Name1, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.First(x => x.Id == 1).Name))
    .ForMember(d => d.Name2, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.First(x => x.Id == 2).Name))
    .ForMember(d => d.Name3, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.First(x => x.Id == 3).Name));
```